# Cannot control startup projects in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, project, startup

Visual Studio 2012 will not allow me to set multiple startup projects.

I have tried:

- Right-click the solution / Set StartUp Projects...

  Result: Nothing happens.
- View / [Property Pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1awth7y%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

  Result: Popup "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

I have no add-ins running, and disabled all extensions that can be disabled without uninstalling.  Active extensions are

- Microsoft Web Developer Tools
- NuGet Package Manager
- Visual Studio Extensions for Windows Library for JavaScript (1.0.8377.0 AND 1.0.9200.20512
- VisualSVN

Is this a known issue?  Is there a fix/work-around?  Can I specify the startup projects by editing the .sln/.csproj file if the VS2012 UI continues to fail?

Comment: Works fine on my machines™.  Not being able to view the property pages of the solution is of course a major fail whale.  First check if it reproduces on a simple solution with two console apps.  If it does then you'll have to do the repair/reinstall song-and-dance.  This setting appears to be saved in the hidden .suo file so editing as a workaround is not an option.  Deleting that file might invoke magic.

Comment: Filed issue on Connect https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/779369/cannot-control-startup-projects-in-visual-studio

Comment: I have exactly the same problem with an old converted solution

Comment: Me too... I'm getting the `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` and there's no `Multiple Startup Projects` options available. See the comments here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13746023/114029 I'll try this.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure this has to do with `NuGet Package Manager`. I did as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13746023/114029).

Uninstalled NuGet Package Manager in `Tools => Extensions and Updates...` and restarted Visual Studio 2012/Visual Studio 2013 Preview. Now I can happily configure my solution properties again!

Installed `NuGet Package Manager` again and the problem reappeared. :(

This is a palliative answer. If there's a definitive answer, please share it! :)

Make sure you vote on this [Connect Bug](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/763961/cannot-open-property-pages-for-solution).

Answer (score 1):

Found this post while searching for a related issue I was having.  I thought it would be helpful for others to know what I found.

My problem was trying to switch between start up projects, IIS Express would always load the same project. My solution was to edit the project properties >Web> assign a different port number for each project.  Now when I select Set as StartUp Project... it actually works

Note** I did not have any issues with NuGet probably because I'm using the released version of 2013

Comment: You are also not configuring for multiple projects to be launched at startup. Also note that I suffer the same problem as the question post on VS 2013 with the VS 2012 project that VS 2012 is editing and originally experienced the issue. All updates applied on both VS2012 and VS2013