# The silverlight 4 SDK is not found error message in windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am developing a small windows phone application, some days I worked fine in building and deploying my Phone APP in to my phone. later I installed visual studio 2013 with update 3 ,after this installation when ever I am trying to build windows phone application I got an error message as "The Silverlight SDK 4 is not installed but I have installed Silverlight SDK 4.

In the designer view I unable to see designer view Main.xaml page and indicating unhandled exception message as "object reference not set to an instance of an object" and Main.xaml page is loaded completely with an exception message

Can anyone please suggest me how can I resolve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try going to your `Tools` > then select `Extensions and Updates` > from the `Updates`, get the latest updates.

Have a look at this one too:

[Visual Studio - Error when clicking on Solution -> Properties (Object reference not set to an instance of an object)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13453109/)

Hope it helps!